# Is the word "too" required?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *L.A Confidential* (1997), Matt and Jack meet each other on sets of Badge of Honor show:

> Matt: Dope, hookers that look like movie stars....Pierce Patchett has
> it all.
>
> Jack: Ha-ha-ha. Boy, you could say that again.
>
> Matt:  Pierce, he's not like regular guys. I mean, I dig him,
> but......you know, he, um, scares me **too**.
>
> Jack: Ha-ha-ha. Boy, you could say that again.

Is the word "too" required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 'required' as such, but it helps make a useful and interesting point. Adding 'too' means '*also*'. The speaker both "digs" (likes) the person, but is *also* scared by them. That could be something of a paradox - to like someone you are scared of. Although you could get the same understanding without the word, using "too" shows that the person has both, conflicting feelings about the person at the same time. Without the word, it could mean that he likes the person *despite* the other fact, which is slightly different, as it could mean he likes being scared.